# How to validate integer in php

Tags: php

** I'm creating a form application using php. This code is not working properly.   I want to show an error `Student ID is required` when it's empty. And the value must contain only 4 digits. No string values and special characters can be entered. All of the above should be validated. how to solve this problem. can any one help me please. thanks... !!! **

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
    <title> Enter Details </title>
        </head>
    <body>


<?php
    $id = "";
    $idErr = ""; 

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
        if (empty($id)){
            $idErr = "Student ID is required";
        }elseif(preg_match('/^\d+$/',$_GET['id'])){
            $idErr = "Only numbers allowed";
        }elseif(strlen($id) != 4) {
            $idErr = "Please enter  4 numbers";
        }
    }

    ?>

<form action = <?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?> method = "post">
    Student ID: <input placeholder="Student ID" type = "text" name= "id" value = ""/> 
    <span class="error">* <?php echo $idErr;?></span></br></br>
        <input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "Register"/> 
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `ctype_digit()` will validate strings like integer values. But your code looks fine to me?

Comment: where I want to put this ?

Comment: In place of `preg_match('/^\d+$/',$_GET['id'])` like `ctype_digit($_GET['ID'])==false`. Your `preg_match` is wrong or should be testing for false. Also your code is switching between `$id` and `$_GET['id']` during your validation...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You define an empty variable and if the post submits you check if it's empty. This will always be true because this variable has an empty string as value. You should try to use `$_POST`. You should also change `$_GET['id']` into `$_POST['id']`:

```
<?php

$idErr = ""; 

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $id = $_POST['id'];

    if (empty($id)){
         $idErr = "Student ID is required";
    } elseif(preg_match('/^\d+$/',$_POST['id'])) {
         $idErr = "Only numbers allowed";
    } elseif(strlen($id) != 4) {
         $idErr = "Please enter  4 numbers";
    }
}

?>
```

You should be able to get a different result if you try this.

Comment: His `preg_match` was wrong too, also worth throwing a `isset($_POST['id'])` in there too

Comment: Thanks. This is the answer. u have to change like this. coz, for your requirement `elseif(!preg_match('/^\d+$/',$_POST['id']))`.

Answer (score 1):

```
    <?php
        $id = "";
        $idErr = ""; 
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
            $idVal = $_POST['id'];
            if (empty($idVal)){
                $idErr = "Student ID is required";
            }elseif(!is_numeric($idVal)){
                $idErr = "Only numbers allowed";
            }elseif(strlen($idVal) != 4) {
                $idErr = "Please enter  4 numbers";
            }
        }
    ?>


//it check like below
   empty->number->exact 4 digit-> success.....
```

Comment: By using `is_numeric($idVal)` that means `12.5` is a valid student ID...